# Powershell script GPO USER LOGON not working WINDOWS SERVER 2019

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, csv

I created Powershell script to collect mac address and pc name for all my domain users ..
Script run correctly on local machine .. but not working via GP

```
$wmifilter = 'PhysicalAdapter=True AND AdapterType LIKE "%ethernet%" AND servicename <> "BthPan"'
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -Filter $wmifilter |     
Select-Object @{n='Tech';e={$env:USERNAME}}, PSComputername, Description, Macaddress |  
Export-Csv -Path \\app-server\mac\mac.csv -Append
```

Comment: Hello, please explain "not working". It's not a phrase you should be using here. You should e.g. provide the error message instead.

Comment: Explain how you have the Group Policy defined, show security filtering too, and explain if it's attached to any specific OUs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is the GP a user or computer policy? If computer, write access to the \app-server\mac\ might be an issue for the system account.

Try adding

```
start-transcript c:\temp\log.txt
```

at the start of the script, replace c:\temp\log.txt with a location users can write to, this might give an idea what is going wrong with the script.

Use `gpresult -v` to verify the GPO is applied

You might also have a problem with code signing, depends on how you tested 'script run correctly on local machine.